# Dúvida sobre validação de POST

Tags: php, html

Eai gente, sou bastante iniciante em php, meu projeto tava dando um:

> notice de undefined index

Então o cara me mostrou esse código para a validação do POST:

```
$texto = isset($_POST['texto']) ? $_POST['texto'] : '';
```

Porém ele não me explicou como funciona, alguém pode me explicar?

Comment: Coloque o código e o erro que surgiu, assim é mais fácil de ajudá-lo

Comment: Na verdade eu queria somente a explicação deste código: $texto = isset($_POST['texto']) ? $_POST['texto'] : '';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa entender o que significa o erro de `undefined`. Esse erro indica que não há um valor na sua variável, com isso, a função `isset` verifica se a variável é definida ou não.

```
$texto = isset($_POST['texto']) ? $_POST['texto'] : '';
```

Seu código também demonstra uma operação ternária (é um `if/else` na versão curta digamos assim)

```
$texto = condição ? TextoDefinido : TextoNaoDefinido;
```

Versão `if/else`:

```
if(isset($_POST['texto'])){
    $texto = $_POST['texto'];
}else{
    $texto = '';
}
```

- [isset()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php)
- [Operador Ternário](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: Muito Obrigado cara, agora eu entendi :D

Answer (score 2):

> O operador ternário é uma versão do `IF…ELSE`, que consiste em agrupar, na mesma linha, os comandos da condição.

**condição tradicional `IF…ELSE`:**

```
$sexo = 'M';

if($sexo == 'M'){
    $mensagem = 'Olá senhor';
}else{
    $mensagem = 'Olá senhora';    
}
```

**condição com operador ternário:**

```
$sexo = 'M';
$mensagem = $sexo == 'M' ? 'Olá senhor' : 'Olá senhora' ;
```

O primeiro parâmetro recebe uma expressão, o segundo é o retorno caso essa expressão seja verdadeira, e o último retorna o valor caso a expressão esteja errada. Assim a variável `$mensagem` fica com o valor `Olá senhor`.

**Sobre, `notice de undefined`** é um simples aviso de que a variável não foi inicializada, ou seja, a variável ainda não tem uma definição.